# Robotframework - appium : WebDriver' object has no attribute 'w3c'

Tags: appium, robotframework, appium-android

I am trying to perform scroll operation using robot framework - appium, but I end up with the error:-
WebDriver' object has no attribute 'w3c'

My code:

```
*** Settings ***
Library  AppiumLibrary

*** Test Cases ***
test_case1
    Open Application    http://localhost:4723/wd/hub    platformName=Android  deviceName=xxx  
    appPackage=com.android.settings  appActivity=com.android.settings.Settings  
    automationName=Uiautomator2
    
    Swipe  200  300  200  100
```

Error observed:-
AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'w3c'

Note:- Other keywords like click element etc are working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Today I have the exact same error as yours. It take me more than 1 hour to figure out what happen.

The problem is the Appium_Python_Client-2.1.2 library. Try to uninstall and reinstall it. And it will fix your error.

Comment: Thanks, ThangTu.
Uninstall and re-install helped solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to downgrade the Appium_Python_Client to version 1.3 and that fixed my issues.

```
pip uninstall Appium-Python-Client
pip install "Appium-Python-Client<2"
```